# Page is blank when I access my github link

Tags: html, reactjs, github

Hello I am trying to learn react right now and I tried to deploy my first web site to the github servers. The problem is that when I deployed it and I access the link the page goes blank and the js/css files can t seem do deploy as well since they get a 404 .
My code:https://github.com/ksXV/monsters
The website:https://ksxv.github.io/monsters/
I tried looking for a solution but nothing seems to work.

Comment: See [deploy react app to gitHub pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)

Comment: You could me more specific with your problems by sharing some other information. Like how you deployed it to the github